# Strange DataTable sorting and keydown behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I've recently added the 'KeyTable' extension to datatable, to navigate through my table with the arrowkeys.

First, I added the following code to get the first record of my table selected:

```
gruposDispTab.cell(':eq(0)').focus();
```

But I get the last record selected:

[image]

Then, with the KeyTable function added, the up arrow key selects the lower row, and the down arrow key selects the upper row; even with that, the inner scroll of my table works fine (up arrow key - scroll goes up, down arrow key, scroll goes down).

I don't know what datatable configuration I need to change to fix this.

P.D.: In case this is needed, this is how I initialized my datatable:

```
gruposDispTab = $('#gruposSelect').DataTable({
    //deferRender: true,
    scrollY: 215,
    scrollX: false,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    scroller: true,
    dom: 't',
    sScrollInner: 702,
    bPaginate: false,
    info: false,
    "destroy": true,
    "keys": true,
    searching: true,
    //orderCellsTop: true,
    "language": {
        "search": "Buscar: ",
        "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron coincidencias",
        "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disabled the ordering in your DataTable.

```
$('#example').dataTable( { 
     "ordering": false
} );
```

source: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ordering

Comment: I need to keep the sorting enabled for that table.